# Factor Analysis Mixed Data in R error

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I am trying to run Factor Analysis Mixed Data in R on a dataframe and using the following command:

```
res.famd <- FAMD(df, graph = FALSE)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error in which(unlist(lapply(listModa, is.numeric))) : 
>       argument to 'which' is not logical

I checked with:

```
str(df)
```

And I get the following:

Gender         : chr  "M" "M" "M" "M" ...
Group          : chr  "LOW" "LOW" "LOW" "LOW" ...
A  : num  3.86e-09 1.90e-091.86e-09 3.63e-09 1.73e-09 ...
B  : num  2.32e-05 5.69e-06 1.86e-05 1.45e-05 1.04e-05 ...
C  : num  0.00249 0.00385 0.01555 0.00853 0.00426 ...

I am trying to convert my variables to a factors but not sure whether I need to do so. I am following the link below where it says that FAMD works with both character and numeric variables:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/115-famd-factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-in-r-essentials/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting char variables to factors.

I.e.

```
df$Gender<- as.factor(df$Gender)
df$Group<- as.factor(df$Group)
```